# ReactJs showing global alert dialog from global helper

Tags: reactjs

I have global helper for `axios` like this:

```
import Axios from 'axios';

const CustomAxios = Axios;

CustomAxios.interceptors.response.use(response => {
    return response;
}, error => {
    const isLogin = error.response.config.url.match(/login/);
    if (+error.response.status === 401 && !isLogin) { // Invalid token
        localStorage.removeItem('jwt_token');
        window.location.href = '/';
    } else if (+error.response.status === 440) { // Expired token, try to refresh first
        return CustomAxios
            .post(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/refresh`, null, {
                headers: {
                    Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('jwt_token')}`
                }
            })
            .then(res => {
                localStorage.setItem('jwt_token', res.data);
                error.config.headers['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${res.data}`

                return CustomAxios.request(error.config);
            })
    } else if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
        alert("Oops.. Something went wrong..\nPlease contact the admin");
    }
    return Promise.reject(error);
})

export default CustomAxios;
```

It went great until my boss tell me to change the alert message to something better like alert dialog from `material-ui`. How do I show this 'global alert' from my global helper? Thanks for answering !

Comment: If you want to keep this global helper uncoupled from any specific components (which is one way to do it), then an option would be to use `react-dom` to manually render a `material-ui` alert dialog onto the page, and have it delete itself in the `onClose`

Comment: @Jayce444 If possible, I want the 'global alert' declared once(May be in my root component). Because I think this is going to be just a static alert

Comment: But then how will you control visibility, a flag in the local state of the root component? If so, then your global script would have to change the local state of a component, and that's generally a bad practice (though not impossible)